Every simplical cycle can be made bounding by adjoining simplices
This question is motivated by the following standard fact about CW-complexes: If $K$ is a cell complex and $z \in Z_k(K)$ a not null-homologous $k$-cycle, then one can form a new CW-complex $L = K \cup_{z} D^{k+1}$ by attaching a new $k+1$-cell whose boundary is precisely $z$, which amounts to killing $[z] \in H_k(K)$. Furthermore, $L$ contains no "new" homology classes; i.e., the induced map $i_*\colon H_k(K) \to H_k(L)$ is surjective.
Question: Is the same true for simplicial complexes? That is, if $K$ is a simplicial complex and $z \in Z_k(K)$ such that $[z] \in H_k(K)$ is non-zero, is there a simplicial complex $L \supseteq K$ such that
$$
0 \to \langle[z]\rangle \to H_k(K) \overset{i_*}{\to} H_k(L) \to 0
$$
is exact?
So far, I've thought the following: if $K$ has $n+1$ simplices, we can embed $K$ into $\Delta^n$. Then $z$ is bounding in $\Delta^n$; say $z = \partial c$ for some $c \in C_{k+1}(\Delta^n)$; now, let $L = K \cup \operatorname{supp} c$. Clearly, $[z] \in \ker i_*$. However, I struggle with surjectivity of $i_*$.
Related question: I call a chain elementary if all its coefficients (w.r.t. the standard basis of $C_k(K)$ are $0$ or $\pm 1$. If $\operatorname{supp} z$ is connected, is it true that $z$ is an integral multiple of an elementary chain?
